# Setting Line Height on UITableViewCell's detailText

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, detailtextlabel

Here I'm using the default UITableViewCell & the thing I don't like is that the detailedText is too close to the textLabel so I wanted to add some spacing between them, but I cannot find how to do that. Any suggestsions?

[image: Simulator's Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Override this below delegate method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: I'm already using that but for other purpose.. 
It's for setting the height of the row & that's not what I need here..
I need to change somehow the height of the detailedText or add some spacing between textLabel & detailText..